# How to set QXmlStreamReader atStart?

Tags: c++, xml, linux, qt

How to set QXmlStreamReader at beginning after pointer have reached at end.

```
 QXmlStreamReader xml(&data);
int i=0;
while(!xml.atEnd()){
    if (xml.isStartElement()) {
     if (xml.name() == "sample") {
    i++;}
    }
    xml.readNext();
}
```

//Here i want to set xml at start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reseting the input source by

```
data.seek(0); // to make QFile object pointing to begining
xml.setDevice(xml.device());
```

[Documentation for setDevice()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#setDevice) says:
 Sets the current device to device. Setting the device resets the stream to its initial state.

Comment: showing error: ‘setDevice’ was not declared in this scope why? @t.m.

Comment: I didn't test it and I can't test now. I will update my unswers when I got the chance

Comment: anything? @t.m.

Comment: you should not just say setDevice, it is a function of QXmlReader. you should say xml.setDevice(xml.device());

Comment: still didn't test though

Comment: What is the type of data at  QXmlStreamReader xml(&data)?

Comment: path of some files.

Comment: Is it a QFile object or a QString

Comment: If data is a Qfile you can go begining of the file with data.seek(0); than again reset xml by
    xml.setDevice(xml.device());

Comment: `QFile data(fileName);` it is @t.m.

Comment: ok than can you try data.seek(0);
    xml.setDevice(xml.device()); This time I tested :)

Comment: if you are using `QByteArray` device is `nullptr`